# Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1') at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to publish my web api that i created using asp.net core 6 to azure it publishes successfully however i get a HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start error when the webapp tries to start when i try to debug it in the console i get the following error

[image]

which points to my programe.cs folder

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyPortfolioWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyPortfolioContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();



//Enable cores

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigion", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
});


//Json Serializer
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

//Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(options=>options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
builder.Services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
app.UseStaticFiles();
//
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(path1:builder.Environment.WebRootPath, "Images"));
var requestPath = "/Images";
//
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = requestPath

});
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = requestPath
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: i am trying to access a images folder that is stored in the wwwroot folder it works fine on my local machine but when i try to publish it i get the HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start error

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample project and using your code. I can reproduce the issue.

You need change your code

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(path1:builder.Environment.WebRootPath, "Images"));
```

to

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(path1:builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Images"));
```

These two methods can be compiled successfully. When I use WebRootPath on my side, the prompt is null, so [I use ContentRootPath according to the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).

We also can check the error logs in kudu site.

[image]

We can find the error in here, you also can use other methods.

And you have `Images` folder in project, so you also need tp include the folder when you build or publish.  I temporarily added the Images folder to wwwroot and the program works fine.

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]